# Is that a conventional way to determine convergence of a series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

given the following sum : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$ determine if convergent or divergent.

we already solved it in class, however after reviewing it later, I stumbled upon this particular nuance: we decomposed it into partial fractions as follows: $\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}=\frac{A}{n+1}+\frac{B}{n+2}$

$1=A(n+2)+B(n+1)$
then we just substituted n=-1, n=-2(values that cancel 'A' or 'B' accordingly)
,found A & B(A=1, B=-1) and then rewrite the new therm, and solved it(**Answer:** the series is convergent and the sum is 0.5).

***My point is:*** I'm not looking for a way to solve it, just to clarify why is it "legal" to susbstitute n=-1 and n=-2 in the partial decomposition section  if we are starting to sum the series from index(in this case letter 'n') **from n=1**?

Comment: The equality $$\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}= \frac{1}{x+1} - \frac{1}{x+2}$$ is true.  Regardless of what the context is.

Comment: It is a technical way to determine the constants   $A$ and $B$. If the decomposition into partial fractions is true, it is true for all values of $n$. We ust take t the values which make calculations particularly simple.

Comment: If it pleases you, you're also allowed to take e.g. $n=245$ and $n=1000$. It ends up being the same.

Comment: Sorry, how can we substitute $n=-1$ or $n=-2$? wouldn't denominator be $0$ and we get division by $0$?